# Iteration over columns problems on condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a Dataset with several columns and a row named "Total" that stores values between 1 and 4.
I want to iterate over each column, and based on the number stored in the row "Total", add a new row with "yes" or "No".
I also have a list "columns" for iteration.
All data are float64

I´m new at python and i don't now if i'm doing the righ way because i´m getting all "yes".

```
for c in columns:
  if dados_por_periodo.at['Total',c] < 4:
    dados_por_periodo.loc['VA'] = "yes"
  else:
    dados_por_periodo.loc['VA'] = "no"
```

My dataset:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what this dataset looks like?

Comment: I edit the post to show a image of my datset.

Comment: What library are you using for storing your `DataSet`? You should tag it.

Comment: I´m using pandas, sorry miis that. I find the problem: Missing the c iteration in the condition = dados_por_periodo.loc['VA',c] = "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I hope it works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#creation of a dummy df
columns='A B C D E F G H I'.split()

data=[np.random.choice(2, len(columns)).tolist() for col in range(3)]
data.append([1,8,1,1,2,4,1,4,1])  #not real sum of values, just dummy values for testing
index=['Otono','Inverno', 'Primavera','Totals']
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns, index=index)
df.index.name='periodo' #just adding index name
print(df)


####Adition of the new 'yes/no' row
df = pd.concat([ df, pd.DataFrame([np.where(df.iloc[len(df.index)-1,:].lt(4),'Yes','No')], columns=df.columns, index=['VA'])])
df.index.name='periodo' #just adding index name
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
           A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
periodo                             
Otono      1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0
Inverno    0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
Primavera  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
Totals     1  8  1  1  2  4  1  4  1


df(with added row)
             A   B    C    D    E   F    G   H    I
periodo                                            
Otono        1   0    0    1    1   0    1   1    0
Inverno      0   1    1    1    0   1    1   1    1
Primavera    1   1    0    0    1   1    1   1    0
Totals       1   8    1    1    2   4    1   4    1
VA         Yes  No  Yes  Yes  Yes  No  Yes  No  Yes
```

Also try to put some data sample the next times instead of images of the dataset, so someone can help you in a better way :)